# XML-client on Android. Connect to server and send data

Tags: android, xml, xml-rpc

I have some problem with XML-RPC on Android.
I include kxmlrpc, and try execute following code:

```
XmlRpcClient client = new XmlRpcClient("http://my.docs-group.ru/xml/",80);

String s;

s="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><request><message><sender>Sender 1</sender> <text>Message 1</text> <abonent phone=\"79234243526\" number_sms=\"1\" phone_id=\"101\"/>   </message>   <security>     <login value=\"user\" />     <password value=\"123456\" />   </security></request>";

client.execute("getResponse", new Vector());
```

Method "execute" required Vector. How I can transform String with xml code to Vector? And is it right what I'm doing (connect to XML server and send data)?

I found information that Android don't work normal with Java code, and method "execute" should be rewritten. (From here http://www.anddev.org/web_services_-_an_xml-rpc_client_for_android-t646.html, point 4). But where I must place my code? I use Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [XML-RPC Examples](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/xml-rpc/xml_rpc_examples.htm) page and [Java XML-RPC Tutorial](http://www.wordtracker.com/docs/api/ch03s02.html) will be helpful. Note that all the parameters of the procedure call are always collected in a Vector.

In this page you pointed, there's all very well explained. If you follow the steps and modify your classes and code like shown there, it works...

Comment: I try to do it, but I can't modify classes in jar file. Can you help me, please?

Comment: I can extract jar file with WinRAR for example

Comment: I have extracted jar files, but they have the extension .class and can not be edited.